# Django does not properly STARTTLS when attempting to email the admins upon internal server error

Tags: django, smtp, smtp-auth, starttls

I have a very strange problem. When an internal server error happens, Django 1.6 attempts to send an email to the admins, and apparently it agrees with the mail server to use TLS, but subsequently fails to use it. Here is the sniffed traffic:

```
T 2a00:1450:400c:c0c::6d:587 -> 2001:648:2ffc:1014:a800:ff:fe6b:e499:49271 [AP]
  220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP lh1sm2677557wjb.20 - gsmtp..                      
##
T 2001:648:2ffc:1014:a800:ff:fe6b:e499:49271 -> 2a00:1450:400c:c0c::6d:587 [AP]
  ehlo peneios.cressendo.org..                                               
##
T 2a00:1450:400c:c0c::6d:587 -> 2001:648:2ffc:1014:a800:ff:fe6b:e499:49271 [AP]
  250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2001:648:2ffc:1014:a800:ff:fe6b:e499].
  .250-SIZE 35882577..250-8BITMIME..250-STARTTLS..250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES..25
  0-PIPELINING..250-CHUNKING..250 SMTPUTF8..                                 
#
T 2001:648:2ffc:1014:a800:ff:fe6b:e499:49271 -> 2a00:1450:400c:c0c::6d:587 [AP]
  STARTTLS..                                                                 
#
T 2a00:1450:400c:c0c::6d:587 -> 2001:648:2ffc:1014:a800:ff:fe6b:e499:49271 [AP]
  220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS..                                             
#
T 2001:648:2ffc:1014:a800:ff:fe6b:e499:49271 -> 2a00:1450:400c:c0c::6d:587 [AP]
  mail FROM:<noreply@hydroscope.gr> size=6578..                              
#
T 2a00:1450:400c:c0c::6d:587 -> 2001:648:2ffc:1014:a800:ff:fe6b:e499:49271 [AP]
  ......F
```

As you can see, although the mail server agreed to start TLS, Django subsequently sent an unencrypted `mail FROM:` directive.

But if I connect to Django with `./manage.py shell` and run this:

```
from django.core.mail import mail_admins
mail_admins('hello', 'hello world')
```

the email is sent correctly:

```
T 2a00:1450:400c:c09::6c:587 -> 2001:648:2ffc:1014:a800:ff:fe6b:e499:53565 [AP]
  220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP i2sm2684051wjx.42 - gsmtp..                       
##
T 2001:648:2ffc:1014:a800:ff:fe6b:e499:53565 -> 2a00:1450:400c:c09::6c:587 [AP]
  ehlo peneios.cressendo.org..                                               
##
T 2a00:1450:400c:c09::6c:587 -> 2001:648:2ffc:1014:a800:ff:fe6b:e499:53565 [AP]
  250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2001:648:2ffc:1014:a800:ff:fe6b:e499].
  .250-SIZE 35882577..250-8BITMIME..250-STARTTLS..250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES..25
  0-PIPELINING..250-CHUNKING..250 SMTPUTF8..                                 
#
T 2001:648:2ffc:1014:a800:ff:fe6b:e499:53565 -> 2a00:1450:400c:c09::6c:587 [AP]
  STARTTLS..                                                                 
#
T 2a00:1450:400c:c09::6c:587 -> 2001:648:2ffc:1014:a800:ff:fe6b:e499:53565 [AP]
  220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS..                                             
#
T 2001:648:2ffc:1014:a800:ff:fe6b:e499:53565 -> 2a00:1450:400c:c09::6c:587 [AP]
  ...........z/x....%....y.F.F..i..8.._w...S...z.0.,.2.../.+.1.-.........(.$.
  ....*.&.....k.j.9.8.'.#.....).%.....g.@.3.2.............E.D.........=.5.<./
[practically nothing readable from this point on]
```

Comment: `EMAIL_USE_TLS = True` ?

Comment: I don't have mail server logs. The mail server is gmail.

Comment: It may not be a django issue. Check if it works at all with your own server. You can use mailhog

Comment: @AviahLaor: After STARTTLS, the mail server says `220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS`. Subsequently, Django sends an unexpected `MAIL FROM`, when it should be negotiating the encryption. Isn't it clear that the mail server side behaves properly, and that something's wrong on the client side?

Comment: One thing I learned from maintaining a mail server is that nothing is clear. STARTLS is by definition a protocol that tries to upgrade plain text **when possible**. If auth fails, or connection errors, mismatch protocol, or ip that is marked as spam (and often blocks of ISP ip's are marked as spam for a few days) or hundred other reasons, this is exactly what you get. And you are right - it could be django issue. So the first step is to check when you can see both sides of the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

The difference between running the system with `./manage.py shell` and running it through the web server is that in the latter case `gevent` is being used. The system was running Debian's `gevent` 1.0.1, which has a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=766867) in SSL code. This raised an exception while Django was starting TLS.

Instead of stopping right at the error, Django pretended that the error hadn't occurred and continued to attempt to send the email, which resulted in the strange behavior shown in the sniff. This is a [Django bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26210).

Comment: Nice  catch, really.

Answer (score 0):

As Antonis mentioned in his answer, it's a Django bug. In my case, I just went for a SMTP server that accepted TSL or no encription. You should find it in almost any email hosted in a cheap shared hosting plan, or at specialized SMTP services providers.